# A simple question on infinite dimensional von Neumann algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Recall a projection $p\in N$ is called *abelian* if $pNp$ is an abelian algebra.

If $N$ is a von Neumann algebra without abelian projections, then can we conclude that $N$ must be infinite dimensional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Because a finite-dimensional von Neumann algebra will always have minimal projections, and minimal projections are abelian.

Comment: Is the minimal projection the projection with one-dimensional range?

Comment: Usually, but not necessarily. Minimal means minimal: no proper subprojections.

Comment: Oh, thanks, Martin :)